# Using a common file for numerous function definitions and calling functions in program from the common file

Tags: function, lua

I have a situation where I have common functions to be used in multiple Lua programs.The requirement is to create these functions and give them the definition/body in a separate file and the file will be shared amongst multiple programs for using definition of the functions.
What kind of file shall I create for storing the function definitions and how can I use this file in my program so that the functions I call in my program get called from that shared common file ?

Answer (score 2):

In Lua, there is no notion of function prototypes as there is in C/C++.

Shared modules are stored in plain `.lua` files, which can be loaded from your other programs using either [`require()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) or [`dofile()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-dofile), depending on your needs.

A common way of structuring your files:

```
-- shared.lua
local shared = {}
function shared.action()
    --[[ code ]]
end
--[[ more definitions ... ]]
return shared
```

```
-- main.lua
local shared = require 'shared'
--[[ call shared.action ]]
```

Comment: You meant "function shared.action()" in shared.Lua.

Comment: Thank you guys, I just needed to put the functions as it is in a .lua file and imported the file using require 'filename' .